# I am trying to create a timed while loop that runs through the code after a certain time

Tags: java

I would like to use a while loop that executes the code inside of it every 5 minutes. This while loop will stop after 20 minutes has passed. Meaning that the code inside the while loop has been passed 4 times.

Comment: Do you have a question? Also, please include the code you have already written.

Comment: Instead of "I would like to", try to ask a question including "this is what I tried"

Comment: Write `while-loop`, stand in front of computer with stopwatch, start stopwatch while simultaneously clicking run in your IDE, once your stopwatch read 5:00 (the digit to the left of the : being minutes and to the right being seconds), click Run once again, repeat 3 more times.

Comment: You'll probably get the best results by using some scheduler/timer, e.g. the built-in `Timer` (Javs SE), `TimerService` (Java EE) or Quartz Scheduler (3rd party lib).

Answer (score 1):

Use Thread.sleep() <-- pass in the milliseconds for which you want to pause.

Run it inside a loop.

Can't give you exact code as you have not shown any efforts from your side.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)? Then you could use a global `int` variable to count how many times the callback has run, and inside the callback, increment it. Also inside the callback, if the counter is >4, stop the timer.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 0;

  while( x < 4 ) {
     // do your stuff
     Thread.sleep(5*60*1000);
     x++;
  }
```